# Change the footer size for only one section in the UITableView

Tags: ios, static, uilabel, uitableview

I have a grouped Static `UITableView` which 4 section. In all 4 sections, I have a header and only the last section has a footer (which is representing the version of the app).

Because I've built up my `UITableViewController` using `Interface Builder` and `Storyboard`, I can set the size of the header and footer margins in the Inspectors and so I've set this to 10 for each.

The problem I'm facing though is the fact that the UILabel that represents the Footer is cut off because of the footer size in the inspector.

I'm using a custom label because I'm placing the footer title in the middle, making it white and changing the size of the font.

Here's the code for that:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 3)
    {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

        UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, screenRect.size.width, 44.0)];

        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, tableView.frame.size.width, 80.0)];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        NSString* currentAppVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version: %@", currentAppVersion];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        [headerView addSubview:label];

        return label;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I increase the size of the footer margin in the Inspector, it increases it for every section and which then makes the gap between the sections much bigger.

I just want to increase the footer of the last section so that the label is not obscured.

I have also tried changing the UIView and UILabel values in the code above but to no luck.

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the delegate method `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`
.

Try something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CGFloat footerHeight = 0;
    if (section == 3) {
        footerHeight = 100;
    }
    return footerHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mats - this did the trick perfectly. I really appreciate your response with this and sorry for the late reply! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT**

The accepted answer above did the trick for my needs, just wanted to convert it to Swift for those in the future.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    var footerHeight: CGFloat = 0

    if section == 3 {
       footerHeight = 100
    }

    return footerHeight
}
```